# How to map over a List using a function returning a Future?

Tags: scala, future

I need a help with Scala Futures and Promises. I am trying to extract historical data from Yahoo. I have written a function which takes in a currency string and a start and end date.

```
def getccyHistory(ccy: String, startDate: String, endDate: String): Future[List[HistoricalCurrency]] = Future {     
  val init  = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22"
  val first = "%3DX%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%22"
  val end   = "%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%22"
  val last  = "%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
  val finalString = init + ccy + first + startDate + end + endDate + last
  val histccy = XML.loadString(Source.fromURL(new URL(finalString)).mkString)
  println ("I am in currency {}", ccy)
  (histccy \ "results" \ "quote") map {x => 
    HistoricalCurrency(
      "JPY", (x \ "Date").text, (x \ "Open").text ,(x \ "High").text,
      (x \ "Low").text, (x \ "Close").text) 
  }.toList
}
```

The following is a list of currencies and I want to get the history of these currencies concurrently. When I try to run the futures, I get List of Promises which I don't know how to extract. I have [read quite a bit](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) on Scala Futures and Promises.

```
val a = List("DKK","JPY","BRL","GBP", "EUR", "SEK")
```

I am attaching the full code for easier understanding.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.promise
import scala.xml._
import java.net._
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}        

case class HistoricalCurrency(
  val ccy   : String,
  val Date  : String,
  val Open  : String,
  val High  : String,
  val Low   : String,
  val Close : String)


def getccyHistory(ccy: String, startDate: String, endDate: String): Future[List[HistoricalCurrency]] = Future {     
  val init  = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22"
  val first = "%3DX%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%22"
  val end   = "%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%22"
  val last  = "%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
  val finalString = init + ccy + first + startDate + end + endDate + last
  val histccy = XML.loadString(Source.fromURL(new URL(finalString)).mkString)
  println ("I am in currency {}", ccy)
  (histccy \ "results" \ "quote") map {x => 
    HistoricalCurrency(
      "JPY", (x \ "Date").text, (x \ "Open").text ,(x \ "High").text,
      (x \ "Low").text, (x \ "Close").text) 
  }.toList
}       

val a = List("DKK","JPY","BRL","GBP", "EUR", "SEK")

val f = a map {x => getccyHistory(x,"2015-07-12","2016-01-11") }
//> f  : List[scala.concurrent.Future[List[Samples.FutureTest.HistoricalCurrenc
//| y]]] = List(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@306cd243, scala.co
//| ncurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3860458b, scala.concurrent.impl.Promis
//| e$DefaultPromise@3875c597, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3bf
//| f5976, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@794a70bf, scala.concurr
//| ent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@63049cf)

f map {x => x.onComplete { case Success(value) => println("Hello")
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Future.traverse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@traverse[A,B,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]]%28in:M[A]%29%28fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[B]%29%28implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]). This will execute a function returning a `Future` for every item in the list (or other collection) and combine the results in one `Future`.

For your currency list this wil give you :

```
val getForCurrency: String => Future[List[HistoricalCurrency]] = 
  getccyHistory(_, "2015-07-12","2016-01-11")

Future.traverse(a)(getForCurrency) 
// scala.concurrent.Future[List[List[HistoricalCurrency]]]
```

You then have just one `Future` instead of a `List[Future[...]]`.

You could have turned the `List[Future[...]]` you received into the same result using `Future.sequence`, but `traverse` does the mapping and the sequencing in one step.

Comment: Thanks Peter I am able to get result.